# Python port scanner using multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, networking

I have written a rather simple port scanner using python and I would like to know things I could do better regarding:

- Code quality, making the code in general better
- Performance, making the code run faster and more efficient
- Making the scan more lightweight for the system being scanned so there is no risk of it crashing

At the moment it takes around 160 seconds to scan all ports.

Thank you in advance.

```
import socket
import time
import threading
from queue import Queue

socket.setdefaulttimeout(0.25)
print_lock = threading.Lock()

target = '127.0.0.1'

def portscan(port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        con = s.connect((target, port))
        with print_lock:
            print('Port', port, 'is open!')
        con.close()
    except:
        pass

def threader():
    while True:
        worker = q.get()
        portscan(worker)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()
startTime = time.time()

for x in range(100):
    t = threading.Thread(target=threader)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

for worker in range(1, 65536):
    q.put(worker)

q.join()

print('Time taken:', time.time() - startTime)
```

Comment: just putting it out there https://stackoverflow.com/a/16780297/1190388